# Call Dynamic Table values Onselect from listItems

Tags: sapui5

I would like to know if possible to get dynamic table values onSelect from listItems.

controller.js

```
onPress : function(oEvent){
            var oSelectedItem = oEvent.getSource();
            var oContext = oSelectedItem.getBindingContext("invoice");
            var sPath = oContext.getPath();
            var oListItem= this.getView().byId("BoM"); 
                oListItem.bindItems({
                          path : "invoice>/ProductHeadSet('12345')/ProductHead2BOM",
                         template : new sap.m.ColumnListItem({
                             cells: [
                                 new sap.m.Text({
                                     text: "{invoice>Material}"
                                 }),
                                 new sap.m.Text({
                                     text: "{invoice>Component}"
                                 }),
                                 new sap.m.Text({
                                     text: "{invoice>Brand}"
                                 })
                                 ]
                         })
                });
    }

});
```

Above is my controller, when i make onPress, i could receive the values from "12345". But when i try to make an dynamic onPress by removing (12345)"invoice>/ProductHeadSet/ProductHead2BOM"". It throws me an error like this "The request URI is invalid. The ProductHeadSet segment refers to an entity set and not to a single entity".

Thanks and Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your answer is right there

> "The request URI is invalid. The ProductHeadSet segment refers to an entity set and not to a single entity".

Int the below code, the number within the brackets help identify which index in the array should be bound to the list.

`invoice>/ProductHeadSet('12345')/ProductHead2BOM`
 Without the number, you are trying to bind the entire array to oListItem.

**EDIT**
This is a little difficult to answer without seeing the model and bindings, But instead of doing
 `path : "invoice>/ProductHeadSet('12345')/ProductHead2BOM"`

Do
`path : "invoice>"+sPath+"/ProductHead2BOM"`

Comment: Yes, i was binding with static model. But i would like to do it with dynamic.

Below url have the same issue which i have found, unfortune i couldn't find the solution. 

https://archive.sap.com/discussions/message/16559631#16559631

Comment: So, How can i achieve this? without the number.

Comment: I have edited the answer to explain. I assumed that the sPath has the value /ProductHeadSet('12345')

Comment: Perfect !!! Thank you for the reply. It was the answer i was looking for.

Comment: Is it possible to know, if i wanted to switch between the iconTabs using the above code. Can be done ?